# Dashes and hyphens in Hebrew

Tags: babel, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm trying to use hyphens in a Hebrew document, but they do not appear in the resulting file. I've created this example to test the error. It seems only the unicode en-dash letter renders correctly when the Hebrew language is selected. Do you know why does this happens?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Hyphen-Minus: Hello-World!

En dash: Hello–World!

Tex en dash: Hello--World!

Tex em dash: Hello---World!

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\L{Maqaf } שלום־עולם!

\L{En dash } שלום–עולם!

\L{Hyphen-Minus } שלום-עולם!

\L{Tex en dash } שלום--עולם!

\L{Tex em dash } שלום---עולם!

\end{document}
```

[image: The compiled example]

Comment: I can't try your example as my system is missing the required fonts and don't know much about hebrew, but this is quite probably a font problem. Imho none of the package for hebrew with (pdf)latex is in good shape. I would suggest that you use xelatex instead.

Comment: I installed ivritex (http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/) for the fonts. I know using xelatex would be better, but I have to use pdflatex to cooperate with other people that only use it.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with MikTeX 2.9 and the [culmus](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html) package... Maybe you should try that instead of ivritex (I'm not sure how well they coexist).

Comment: Do you think it will work on Mac?

Comment: @haggai_e: No idea. Googling yields [this](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~yoavg/tech-notes/heblatex/), but that may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I've used in the first place.